# Unexpected result from JOIN and GROUP_CONCAT with three tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join, group-concat

here's an link to the schema and sql: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d99b6/8

Schema:

```
create table movies (
  id int,
  movie_name varchar(20)
  );

create table genre (
  movie_id int,
  genre varchar(20)
  );

create table actors (
  movie_id int,
  actor_name varchar(20)
  );

insert into movies (id, movie_name)
  values
    (1, 'asdf');

insert into genre (movie_id, genre)
  values
    (1, 'Comedy'),
    (1, 'Thriller');

insert into actors (movie_id, actor_name) 
  values
    (1, 'actor1'),
    (1, 'actor2');
```

Sql:

```
select movies.id,
  movies.movie_name,
  group_concat(genre.genre separator ', ') as genre,
  group_concat(actors.actor_name separator ', ') as actors
from movies
inner join genre on genre.movie_id = movies.id
inner join actors on actors.movie_id = movies.id;
```

I want to output this:

```
id    movie_name    genre               actors
1     asdf          Comedy, Thriller    actor1, actor2
```

But get this instead:

```
id    movie_name    genre                                 actors
1     asdf          Comedy, Thriller, Comedy, Thriller    actor1, actor1, actor2, actor2
```

Not sure how to go about this problem, help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should include sample data in your question, along with the query.  SQL Fiddle is not always up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `distinct:

```
select m.id, m.movie_name,
       group_concat(distinct g.genre separator ', ') as genres,
       group_concat(distinct a.actor_name separator ', ') as actors
from movies m inner join
     genre g
     on g.movie_id = m.id inner join
     actors a
     on a.movie_id = m.id
group by m.id;
```

If you have lots of data for each movie, then the `distinct` adds extra overhead.  The `join`s do a Cartesian product of genres and actors for each movie.  You can handle that by pre-aggregating or using correlated subqueries:

```
select m.id, m.movie_name,
       (select group_concat(g.genre separator ', ')
        from genre g
        where g.movie_id = m.id 
       ) as genres,
       (select group_concat(a.actor_name separator ', ')
        from actors a
        where a.movie_id = m.id
       ) as actors
from movies m;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `DISTINCT`:

```
select movies.id,
  movies.movie_name,
  group_concat(DISTINCT genre.genre separator ', ') as genre,
  group_concat(DISTINCT actors.actor_name separator ', ') as actors
from movies
inner join genre on genre.movie_id = movies.id
inner join actors on actors.movie_id = movies.id;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d99b6/10/0)**</kbd>